# Read-write mount both hidden + regular TrueCrypt volume at same time?

Tags: truecrypt

Can I read-write mount both a regular TrueCrypt volume AND a hidden 
volume inside the regular volume at the same time?

The general idea would be to use the outer volume for non-sensitive 
stuff and the inner hidden volume for sensitive stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the nature of TrueCrypt, you cannot mount both volumes at the same time. Basically, TrueCrypt takes your password and tries to decrypt the hidden volume header. If it fails, it tries the "standard" header. This way an adversary for example has no way of knowing you have a hidden volume since you're only typing in a specific password to pull the volume of your choice.

That said, your "standard" volume should just be used for dummy data anyway. If you need both,  just use two files/partitions for your volumes.

Edit: Oh, and you can't assign 2 drives to it since it's an exclusive lock (you'd get greeted with an "already mounted" error).

Answer (score 1):

Yep this is perfectly possible. You just need to make a normal Truecrypt volume, mount it and then just create a hidden volume pointing somewhere inside your mounted Truecrypt volume.

Comment: Oh, I've already done that part. The question is how do I *mount* the hidden volume. It's not associated with a filename (except the one I gave the normal volume). I have the "protect hidden volume" flag set, but that just prevents me from writing to it from the normal volume; it doesn't mount it for me.